# vim - open files containing a specific string in new tabs

Tags: vim, vi

I am looking for a way to open all files that contain a specific string in new vim tabs.

The files are not in a specific directory, but scattered across a directory tree.

Ideally I want to jump to the position of the string match in each file.

Even better if it can be executed form within vim

Answer (score 2):

it's not exactly what you're looking for, but you can find all files containing your string as follows:

```
:grep -r "string" directory
```

and then browse the results using:

```
:copen
```

that opens a `quickfix` window containing the results, and then you can get up/down in the list, and press `<CR>` to load that file at the matched line in a new buffer.

It's the vim way of grepping. Of course, you can use `:vimgrep` instead, or use the [Grep plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=311) or the [Ack plugin](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim). The ack plugin has a feature to open the result in a new tab, if you press `t` instead of `<CR>` on a result line.

Comment: is there a way to set 'directory' to pwd and sub-directories so I don't type it every time?

Comment: Use a dot: `:grep -r "string" .`

Answer (score 2):

You could put the following in your .vimrc file:

```
com! -nargs=+ PatternFilesToTabs call s:PatternFilesToTabs(<q-args>)

function! s:PatternFilesToTabs(pattern)
    let savelz=&lz
    let savlast=@#
    let savfile=@%
    let hash={}
    let files=[]
    sil! redir => result
    exec 'sil! grep ' . a:pattern . ' -r .'
    sil! redir end
    for line in split(result, '\n')
        if (match(line, ':\d\+:') > 0)
            let filen=substitute(line, ':.*', '', '')
            if (!has_key(hash,filen))
                let hash[filen] = 1
                let files += [ filen ]
            endif
        endif
    endfor
    for filen in files
        exec 'sil! tabedit ' . filen
        1
        sil! call search(a:pattern)
    endfor
    exec 'sil! tabp ' . len(files)
    exec 'sil! edit ' . savlast
    exec 'sil! edit ' . savfile
    let &lz=savelz
endfunction
```

Comment: And how should I use it after that?

Comment: To use just do `:PatternFilesToTabs pattern`

Answer (score 0):

To open the files containing `"*backup-file.*.sh"` shell glob pattern string straight from the bash shell use the following oneliner ( yes you could modify the find command as long as you obey the single quoting

```
   # in bash
   vim -c ':args `find . -type f -name '\''*backup-file.*.sh'\''`'
```

Comment: Your answer could benefit from more detail (See [answer]). Please edit it to explain how  your solution works/how it addresses the OPs question.